# Splitting file in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .TXT file containing account numbers. Sample:
TRV001 TRV002 TRV003 TRV004... The values are separated by space.
I want to split this file containing first 1000 account numbers in one file and next 1000 accounts in the next file using bash.These account numbers are coming from a report so we don't know how many account number are we going to get in the file.

Comment: If you don't know where to begin, I suggest checking `man split`.

Comment: What naming scheme should be used to create the files?

Comment: Is it an option to NOT use a bash-script but maybe a python-script? That might be a lot easier.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the source file is called acc, you can use awk piped through to split

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { print $i } }' acc | split -l 1000
```

For field in each line, print the field on a separate line using awk and then put the output in separate files (default prefix x) using split

Comment: You don't really need Awk here. `xargs printf ´%s\n' < acc`. If you can't fix the program which generates this wacky format, probably do this as a postprocessing step immediately after generating this file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help, I was able to work it out. I changed the format of the file to have only one account number per line of the file and then used split -l 1000 to split the files.